# Magento 2: Why my multi store isn't loading CSS?

Tags: magento2, multistore, css, deploy

I've set up multi-store with multi-domain, but I'm facing a weird issue that is default store is running perfectly but another store is not able to load CSS.

Please help

Comment: @Rafael, Please help. I am having bad day.

Comment: What are the error messages that are showing in the browser console?

Comment: All stuff going to 404.

Comment: Yes, I've encounter one problem that i set up multi store with multi domain. I have domain folder under public_html/domain1 Also main domain pointing to magento that is public_html/magento_installation. If i exit in magento root at index.php it worked with main domain. But not exit on second domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run these commands in your root installation folder using your SSH access:

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento"

chmod -R 775 pub/static/ var/ pub/media/ &&
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/tmp/ var/generation/ pub/static/frontend/ ;
mage deploy:mode:set developer;
mage setup:upgrade &&
mage setup:db-data:upgrade &&
mage dev:source-theme:deploy &&
mage setup:static-content:deploy &&
mage cache:flush &&
mage indexer:reindex;
chmod -R 775 pub/static/ pub/media/ var/
```

Comment: I have tried all.

Answer (score 3):

Have you assigned the theme to the new store? if so then have you redeployed the site also reindex the data and finally flushed the cache

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB en_US
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Yes i have assigned theme to store.
Also verified try with upgrade and deploy command

Comment: did you reindex?

Comment: Yes, I've encounter one problem that i set up multi store with multi domain.

I have domain folder under public_html/domain1

Also main domain pointing to magento that is public_html/magento_installation.

If i exit in magento root at index.php it worked with main domain. But not exit on second domain.

Comment: Have you setup your stores in your htaccess file? also if you iew the page source is it displaying the correct urls for the style sheet?

Comment: I don't want to modify any file like index.php and .htaccess. I want to setup without editing them.