# Magento 2: Multistore with the same domain

Tags: magento2, multistore, index, domain, index.php

I want to have many sites with the same domain, for example, example.com/site1, example.com/site2, and so on...

This is what I've done by far:

1- Change base URL of the site for example.com/site1

2- Create a folder inside root/site1 and add index.php file on site1 folder.

3- Modify the index.php folder with the website code.

4- Create in Pub/site1 folder and again add index.php

I can access the page example.com/site1, but it has no styles or design, also if I click to any of the links it redirects me to example.com and throws 404 error.

Thanks!

Comment: Try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194218/magento-2-why-my-multi-store-isnt-loading-css

Comment: copy .htaccess from root to root/site1

Comment: I have already copied it, did not work :(

Comment: I have already submitted the answer and it is working perfectly
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/193679/magento-2-how-to-set-multi-websites-on-the-same-url/351729#351729

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Add Store Code to Urls (select Yes). Delete cache and you will see your second store by code of store view

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

In Stores>Configuration>(choose site, not default config)>web

I typed this

in Base URL for Static View Files: example.com/pub/static

in Base URL for User Media Files: example.com/pub/media

In addition I followed this answer:

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Admin-Configuration/Magento-2-Multi-website-single-domain-configuration/td-p/94275

Greetings!