# Magento 2 - Redirect customers to correct store on login using the same url

Tags: magento2, multistore, login, store-switcher, store-id

My site requires customers to login via third party to a multistore on magento 2 using the **same url** (no store code in url).
I have 3 websites with corresponding stores, views and customer groups.

Ideally, I want a system where every customer logs into the same default store/website and gets **automatically** switched to a specific store based on their customer group once logged in.

At the moment I can only use the `store` cookie to switch between stores and that's about it.
So far all i am unable to find solutions that don't include subdomains (i have to keep the url the same for each store).

I've found the below articles but neither seems to help

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Admin-Configuration/Magento-2-Multi-website-single-domain-configuration/td-p/94275

[Magento 2: Multistore with the same domain](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293499/magento-2-multistore-with-the-same-domain?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Is this doable? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I should add that the complication in this is the default website. I can set any of the 3 websites as the default site and the customers can log in with no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect store based on customer group after login.

Please try below code and manage as per your need.

Create events.xml file

Path:   app/code/Mpr/StoreViewSwitcher/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_login">
        <observer name="customer_login_observer" instance="Mpr\StoreViewSwitcher\Observer\CustomerLogin" />
    </event>

</config>
```

Create CustomerLogin.php file

Path:  app/code/Mpr/StoreViewSwitcher/Observer/CustomerLogin.php

```
<?php

namespace Mpr\StoreViewSwitcher\Observer;

use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CustomerLogin implements ObserverInterface
{
    
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManagerInterface;

    protected $httpContext;

    protected $storeCookieManager;

    protected $storeRepository;
    
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context  $httpContext,
        \Magento\Store\Api\StoreCookieManagerInterface  $storeCookieManager,
        \Magento\Store\Api\StoreRepositoryInterface  $storeRepository,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManagerInterface
    ) {
        $this->httpContext              = $httpContext;
        $this->storeCookieManager       = $storeCookieManager;
        $this->storeRepository          = $storeRepository;
        $this->_storeManagerInterface   = $storeManagerInterface;
    }


    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {   

        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        
        //$mycode    = strtolower($customer->getMycode());   
        $mycode    = 'your customer group code';  // make change as per requirement
        
        switch ($mycode) {
            case "storeViewCode1":
                $store = $this->storeRepository->getActiveStoreByCode('storeViewCode1'); // storeViewCode1 your store view code
                $this->httpContext->setValue(Store::ENTITY, 'storeViewCode1', 'english'); // english is default store view code
                $this->storeCookieManager->setStoreCookie($store);        
                break;
            case "storeViewCode2":
                $store = $this->storeRepository->getActiveStoreByCode('storeViewCode2');
                $this->httpContext->setValue(Store::ENTITY, 'storeViewCode2', 'english');
                $this->storeCookieManager->setStoreCookie($store);                  
                break;
            default:
                $store = $this->storeRepository->getActiveStoreByCode('english');
                $this->httpContext->setValue(Store::ENTITY, 'english', 'english');
                $this->storeCookieManager->setStoreCookie($store);                
        }
        
    }
}
```